# Role/Permission issues writing to AWS DynamoDB from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am getting these errors on a write to AWS Dynamo from a lambda function.  I think it is something about how I have the roles linked.

> message: 'User:
>   arn:aws:sts::086883031465:assumed-role/lambda_basic_execution/awslambda_865_20160718210221776
>   is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:086883031465:table/DeviceReadings',   code:
>   'AccessDeniedException',   time: Mon Jul 18 2016 21:03:43 GMT+0000
>   (UTC),   requestId:
>   'G0VU59A8FOA4NI0EMJSI6A50DRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',   statusCode:
>   400,   retryable: false,   retryDelay: 0 }

Here is my configuration

```
Lambda
Runtime - Node.js 4.3
Handler - index.handler
Role - Use an existing role
Existing Role - lambda_basic_execution

IAM
Role (created by me) - lambda_basic_execution
Policy attached to role - Accesstodynamo
InLine policies - 
  oneClick_lambda_basic_execution_1467010842260
  oneClick_lambda_basic_execution_1467695976683 

Accesstodynamo policy
{

"Version": "2012-10-17",

"Statement": [

        {

           "Action": [

                "logs:CreateLogGroup",

                "logs:CreateLogStream",

                "logs:PutLogEvents"

            ],

            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/*",

            "Effect": "Allow"

        },

        {

            "Action": [

                "dynamodb:PutItem"

            ],

            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/EC2Scheduler-OptIn"

            ],

            "Effect": "Allow"

        },

        {

            "Action": [

                "lambda:AddPermission",

                "lambda:CreateFunction",

                "lambda:DeleteFunction",

                "lambda:GetFunction",

                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",

                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration",

                "events:DeleteRule",

                "events:DisableRule",

                "events:EnableRule",

                "events:PutEvents",

                "events:PutRule",

                "events:PutTargets",

                "events:RemoveTargets",

                "events:ListTargetsByRule",

                "s3:GetObject",

                "iam:PassRole"

            ],

            "Resource": "*",           
            "Effect": "Allow"

        }

    ]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your policy only gives `PutItem` permission for the table `EC2Scheduler-OptIn`. You need to add a statement in there for table `DeviceReadings`.

Change this part:

```
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/EC2Scheduler-OptIn"

        ],
```

To this:

```
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/EC2Scheduler-OptIn",
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/DeviceReadings"
        ],
```

Comment: Many thanks!   First time in this environment. Really appreciate the help.